# Cheerio find function include ancestor with descendant

Tags: javascript, cheerio

I would like to get the HTML for both the `<td>` and the descendant like so.

```
<td
  id="cell20_2"
  class="txtbold"
  align="center"
  bgcolor="white"
  onmouseover='doTooltipV(event,0, "28/01/2021 (Thur)","3","11:30","13:10","BBDC"); SetMouseOverToggleColor("cell20_2") '
  onmouseout='hideTip(); SetMouseOverToggleColor("cell20_2")'
>
  <input
    type="checkbox"
    id="20_2"
    name="slot"
    value="1997905"
    onclick="SetCountAndToggleColor('cell20_2', 'varSlotCount')"
  />
</td>
```

This is what I use to filter `<td>` with the attribute `onmouseover`.

```
parseSlotsListing = (data) => {
  const $ = cheerio.load(data);
  $(
    "#myform > table:nth-child(2) > tbody > tr:nth-child(10) > td > table > tbody"
  )
    .find("td[onmouseover]")
    .each(function (i, elem) {
      console.log("-------START---------");
      console.log($(this).html());
      console.log("-------END---------");
    });
};
```

However, I am getting

```
<input
    type="checkbox"
    id="20_2"
    name="slot"
    value="1997905"
    onclick="SetCountAndToggleColor('cell20_2', 'varSlotCount')"
  />
```

I would like to get both the input and td as the output. I have tried getting the parent and it returns the entire row which contains multiple `<td>` which is not the expected result.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you want:

```
$.html(elem)
```